# Postpone responding to request in Node.js

Tags: node.js

When my Node.js Express server, which is listening on port 3000, receives a request, it routes to a function that must issue a POST to another Web site and get the response before responding to the initial request.

Is that possible?

### Here is the code I'm using:

```
app.get('/silence/:host', routes.silence);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

---

```
exports.silence = function(request, response){
   var hostname = utils.validateHost(request);
   if (stash.createSilencer(hostname)) {
      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
      response.write('{ "success" : true, "message" : "Successfully silenced host'" }');
      response.end();
   }
}
```

---

```
exports.createSilencer = function(hostname) {
   var options = {
      url: 'http://x.x.com:4567/create/silencer/' + hostname ,
      method: 'POST',
      body: '{ "timestamp": ' + utils.timestamp() + '} '
   };
   request(options, silencer_callback);
   ##### DONT WANT TO RETURN UNTIL THE silencer_callback IS INVOKED
   return true;
}
```

---

```
function silencer_callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var info = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("Response Recieved");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure it's possible, it's how it works, you get a request, create some data, return a response. Can we help you out, no we can't as you didn't post any code, and this should be trivial to at least get started on your own.

Comment: As adeneo said, yes this is possible.  In fact, it would be hard to write code that *didn't* work this way as almost everything in node works off of callbacks and events.  Post your code if you want help on a specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is that you don't call `response.write()` and `response.end()` until you receive a response from you POST request. You just exit the method without sending response back. Once you have result from your POST request, you can finish initial response.

```
exports.silence = function(req, res){    
    var hostname = utils.validateHost(req);
    stash.createSilencer(hostname, function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var info = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("Response Received");
      }
      // we get POST-response, lets response to initial request here
      res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
      res.write('{ "success" : !error, "message" : "Successfully silenced host'" }');
      res.end();
    });
    // return from the function, but do not send response back yet
}

exports.createSilencer = function(hostname, callback) {
    var options = {
        url: 'http://x.x.com:4567/create/silencer/' + hostname ,
        method: 'POST',
        body: '{ "timestamp": ' + utils.timestamp() + '} '
    };
    request(options, callback);
    // return from the function, but do not send response back yet
}
```

Comment: It looks good. Except that the "response" variable being passed into the exports.silence function is different than the "response" being returned by the callback. The callback is returning the "response" to the POST. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little thick. I understand and it works like a charm.,